# Finding occurence pattern in a timestamp interval

Tags: python, algorithm, timestamp

Given an array of timestamps (epoch time), where each timestamp represents the time when an event occured

```
timestamps = [1467267654, 1467267657, 1467267660, ... 146726821]
```

I must search for an interval of 30 seconds where the number of occurences is higher than 5.

So, if there are at least 5 items between **i** and **j**, and **timestamps[j]-timestamps[i] <= 30 seconds**, then return true.

What is the proper algorithm to use here? Keep in mind I'm using python so maybe it's already implemented under numpy. Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: are your data sorted ?

Comment: yes, the array is sorted

Comment: Please specify unambiguously what you mean by "at least 5 items between". How much must `j-i` be ?

Comment: j-i should be 4 , meaning 5 elements are between i and j

Comment: The problem with "between" is that you don't know if it is inclusive or not; and with base 0 indexing, it is customary to speak left-inclusive/right-exclusive, so there are at least three interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is sorted, one pass is enough. Iterate through the array in the following manner:

- remember the current index `i`, let's call this index `start`
- increase `i` until either `i = start + 4` or `a[i] > a[start] + 30`: in the first case return `true`, in the second case update `start = start + 1` and proceed

Total complexity: `O(n)`.

**Bonus**

- if you want to return all such intervals, then in case when you found an appropriate interval, remember its bounds and proceed
- if you want to return the longest such interval, then don't stop when you find `i = start + 4` such that `a[i] < a[start] + 30`, but extend the interval further. When you finally meet index `j` such that `a[j] > a[start] + 30` remember the bounds of this currently longest interval, update `start = start + 1` and proceed

Comment: Trying the intermediate elements between `start` and `start + 5` is overkill, it is enough to compare the two extremes to conclude. In the worst case you are performing 5 times the work needed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Agree. I was aware of that while writing an answer, but for a small interval size (in this case 5), asymptotically it does not make a huge difference (and it was better than the other proposed solution which was O(nlogn)). Your solution is definitely more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try all pairs of timestamps 4 indexes apart until you find one that differs by less than 30 seconds.

```
for i in range(len(timestamps) - 4):
    if timestamp[i + 4] - timestamp[i] <= 30:
        return true
return false
```

After the problem statement, there is no need to report the interval position. The loop takes exactly `I+1` comparisons, where `I` is the index of the first matching interval (`N - 4` if there is none).

Best case `1` comparison, worst case `N-4`, expected case `p(E(I)+1)+(1-p)(N-4)` where `E(I)` is the expectation of `I` and `p` is the probability that there exists a suitable interval.

---

In a more modern and notably inefficient style (`timestamp` shortened to `t`),

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a or b, [t[i + 4] - t[i] <= 30 for i in range(len(t) - 4)])
```